# jQuery-ui-1.10.3 position conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There seems to be a problem using this function with jQuery-ui-1.10.3.

```
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}
```

When trying to position something relative to the window like so.

```
var box = $('#box');
box.css('display','block');
box.position({
    my: "center",
    at: "center",
    of: window
});
```

The division that I am attempting to positing gets positioned to the top left part of the screen (barely visible). This wasn't an issue with jQuery-ui-1.8.17.

style

```
#box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;   
}
```

Apparently there seems to be some conflict. Could someone explain to me what exactly is happening?

Comment: Unable to reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/qqy8y/ . Perhaps I misunderstood, can you please explain what is incorrect with this fiddle - or what it should or should not do?

Comment: When I include jQuery-ui-1.10.3 there seems to be a conflict with function preventDefault and the positioning goes haywire. This conflict is not there when I include jQuery-ui-1.18.17.

Comment: What is your preventDefault function supposed to do? I'm also having trouble recreating your issue (with jQuery-ui 1.10.3) http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/qqy8y/2/